# C# Invalid report file path

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, export

I need help in solving an error on crystal reports, I'm trying to export data from crystal report to PDF file

[image]

Invalid report file path. Can some one help me?  thanks

[image]

Comment: @PaulZahra I use Load report also but here i got some more error please see my question image sir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code :

```
CrystalReport1 crystal = new CrystalReport1();


    crystal.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "YOUR FILE PATH\ReportAsPDF.pdf");
     MessageBox.Show("Report Export Into PDF File");
```

hope its useful for you.

Comment: Please explain your answer.